# Simple Js function giving me undefined as output

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve this simple js function question but its giving the undefined as output along with the correct answer. I know its probably because of the return value issue but how solve in this situation?

```
function findMax(a,b,c){
    if(a>b && a>c){
        console.log("a" + " is max")
    }else if(a<b && b>c){
        console.log("b" + " is max")
    }else{
        console.log("c" + " is max")
    }
}
console.log(findMax(2,4,5))
```

Comment: you don't need to `console.log` the function as function is already doing that for you. Simply call function and it'll work.

Comment: why you doing console.log(findMax(2,4,5)) instead of this try this findMax(2,4,5)

Comment: You can also find maximum number like this `return Math.max(num1, num2, num3);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your console logging the return value which is undefined. just get rid of the last con sole log.

```
function findMax(a,b,c){
    if(a>b && a>c){
        console.log("a" + " is max")
    }else if(a<b && b>c){
        console.log("b" + " is max")
    }else{
        console.log("c" + " is max")
    }
}
findMax(2,4,5);
```

Or you could return the string

```
function findMax(a,b,c){
    if(a>b && a>c){
        return "a" + " is max";
    }else if(a<b && b>c){
        return "b" + " is max";
    }else{
        return "c" + " is max";
    }
}
console.log(findMax(2,4,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value out to the outermost level.
You can just return simple string, so you can log or do something else to the returned value.

```
function findMax(a, b, c) {
    if (a > b && a > c) {
        return "a" + " is max"
    } else if (a < b && b > c) {
        return "b" + " is max"
    } else {
        return "c" + " is max"
    }
}
console.log(findMax(2, 4, 5))
```